# How to POST a request within same session launched website, using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, session, cookies, request

I am trying to achieve the following using Sentinel:

- Open a website
- POST a request to website server like the website would.

Problem is that I cant make the POST within the same session what had been created when website launched.

I tried to get all cookies, create proper header, etc, but couldnt manage it.

```
#--------------------------
    def monitor_network_logs ():
    
        while True:
    
            logs = driver.get_log('performance')
            
            for log in logs:
            
                message = log['message']        
    
                if "json?h=" in message: 
    
                    start_index = message.find('?h=') + 3
                    end_index = message.find('"', start_index)
                    json_id = message[start_index:end_index]
    
                    print ("json value: " + json_id)
            return json_id
            
            time.sleep (2)  
#--------------------------
    
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    import time
    import requests
    import json

    json_id = ""
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")
    options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
    
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    action = ActionChains(driver) 
    
    try:
    
        driver.get("....")  
        monitor_network_logs ()
     
        url = '...../json?h=' + json_id
        
        payload = [...]
    
        json_data = json.dumps(payload)
        content_length = len(json_data.encode('utf-8'))
        sid = driver.session_id
    
        all_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        cookies_dict = {cookie['name']: cookie['value'] for cookie in all_cookies}
        cookie_header = '; '.join([f"{name}={value}" for name, value in cookies_dict.items()])
    
        instanceId = next((cookie['value'] for cookie in all_cookies if cookie['name'] == 'instanceId'), None)
        metricsUvId = next((cookie['value'] for cookie in all_cookies if cookie['name'] == 'metricsUvId'), None)
        cid = next((cookie['value'] for cookie in all_cookies if cookie['name'] == 'cid'), None)
    
        headers = {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "Client-Identification": "version=1.275; requiredVersion=1.275; platform=bro; platformType=html5; platformVersion=web",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": str(content_length),
            "Cookie":f"instanceId={instanceId}; metricsUvId={metricsUvId}; sid={sid}; cid={cid}; ig_conv_last_site=...",
            "Origin": "....",
            "Referer": "....",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "Signature": "0c5b3a00a6"
        }
    
        headers = {"Cookie": f"sid={sid}"}
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.text)
    
    finally:
        
        driver.quit()
```